# What events should go through the RAFT log

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-system, raft

I'm a little confused with the RAFT log driving the state machine of my system

Let's take Kafka as an example,

- Every partition has a leader & a replica, does that mean there's a RAFT instance per partition?

IF yes, then every time a producer sends a record, should it be persisted in the RAFT log before appending to the Kafka partition?

IF no,  then how does Kafka maintain leader & replica to be in sync during failures?

- Consensus is confusing me

There are multiple consensus points IMO and I'm unsure where to use RAFT and where it's not required. e.g. the cluster leader election, partition leader, even replication is a form of consensus to me

Other doubts regarding RAFT

- It is said that followers should update their state machine only after a commit is done, what if a follower is isolated and ends up committing the wrong event? Is this even possible? IF yes, should the state machine have logic for rollbacks? From my experience with elastic search, there always should be a rollback mechanism for obsolete events

I'm trying to implement something similar to Kafka for learning purpose and I'm confused at the point where I don't even know how to begin implementing one

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the Kraft code is open source https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/raft

Comment: I've tried looking into the code. It's complicated to understand. I think what makes it complicated because I don't know how distributed systems are designed

Comment: So I understand all the administrative tasks of creating topics, assigning partitions, membership status, the primary and replica should go through the raft log so that all the nodes are consistent. My primary doubt was how primary and replicas are kept in sync? Should every event go through the raft log? Is that too much of an overhead?

Comment: Okay, well, prior to this (which is still in beta phase), Kafka doesn't use Raft. It uses Zookeeper's ZAB for leader election... Unclear if you're asking specifically about Kafka or just how Raft works at a fundamental level

Comment: I'm not super knowledgeable about the Kafka protocol, but I think only watermarks are transfered between leaders and replicas via the election protocols. Replica Fetcher threads are responsible for keeping data in sync via the standard Consumer APIs, AFAIK

Comment: kafka moved away from zookeeper

Comment: I said "prior to this", and still not completely. Like I said, the feature is still "opt in" and in beta acceptance

Comment: i'm surprised i missed this, http://book.mixu.net/distsys/replication.html#:~:text=Replicated%20systems%20that%20maintain%20single,messages%20(synchronous%20primary%2Fbackup)

Comment: it suggests replication need not go through a consensus protocol. for me the confusion was around the fact that replication in itself is consensus between primary & replica

Comment: I think you're conflating Kafka message replication with metadata replication. The non-leader partitions do need to know what high watermark the leader has, compared to their own, and they ought to agree on that value, which is "replicated" between them

Comment: what's a watermark in kafka? is it the term number?

Comment: nevermind, found it. it's the last successfully replicated offset

Comment: @FaizHalde You are right in that the complete system state needs to be in absolute consistent state in the controllers and hence should be replicated using the Raft log. But for partition repliaction kafka need not use Raft. It instead sends hearbeat between the known Followers and maintains internal ISR (replication state). The consistency of the replicated message con be controlled via config for eg: whether in should by synchronous or async etc. Raft is used only for the metadata information for etc partition leader, followers, updating replicas when one/few of them fails etc.